What's the flexibility in concrete types mentioned by Bjarne Stroustroup?
In Chapter 5.2 of the 3rd edition of  A Tour of C++, Bjarne write this about concrete types. What I don't understand is what the flexibility is.

Is he referring to the use of pointers in concrete classes?
Is the flexibility the lack of recompilation of the objects in the heap when their definition changes because the pointer size will still be the same?


The representation can be private and accessible only through the
member functions (as it is for  Vector; §2.3), but it is present.
Therefore, if the representation changes in any significant way, a
user must recompile. This is the price to pay for having concrete
types behave exactly like built-in  types. For types that don’t change
often, and where local variables provide much-needed clarity  and
efficiency, this is acceptable and often ideal. To increase
flexibility, a concrete type can keep  major parts of its
representation on the free store (dynamic memory, heap) and access
them through  the part stored in the class object itself. That’s the
way vector and string are implemented; they can  be considered
resource handles with carefully crafted interfaces.


Your interpretation is a bit narrow.  He's referring to indirection (the object contains something that refers to another object outside itself).  Pointers are one of a number of ways to achieve indirection.  And, yes, using indirection can help reduce need for recompilation (e.g. can change implementation of a class's member functions, but - as long the definition of the class itself is unchanged - not be forced to recompile every source file which uses that class).  Pointer size being the same is only one aspect of that.

@Peter,  What are other forms of indirection?

@Peter, by definition of the class, you mean the addition or removal member variables and/or addition or removal of member functions? If so, how would the pointer change? I may be confused about pointer size - I thought that all pointers had the same size whether they are for ints or a bigger object.

Other forms of indirection include references, indices into an external array.    If the class contains some data that is used to find a resource that exists outside the class (e.g.  an index that is used to find an element of a global array that is not part of the class) then the class is using indirection.

The meaning of "class definition" is specified in the standard.  Practically, it is a class declaration that includes that class's members, member functions, etc.   So class A; is a declaration that is not a definition.   But class A {public: A();  private: int a;}; is a class definition.

And, no, pointers of different types are not required to be the same size.  There are real-world cases (e.g. targeting hardware with segmented memory models, and different data types are placed in physically different memory banks) in which pointers of some types are smaller than other pointers. The standard does require that all pointers (excluding member pointers which, despite the name, are not actually pointers) can be converted to void * and back - practically, that means a void * cannot be smaller than any other pointer.

I think the answer to both questions is Yes.
Any complex data that depends on the design of the class implementation should be stored on the heap. So std::vector could be implemented as
template <type T>
class vector {
private:
    vector_implementation<T>* data;
...
}

Then all the methods of vector simply call a corresponding method in vector_implementation, e.g.
void vector<T>::push_back(T val) {
    data->push_back(val);
}

If you need to make changes to the implementation, you change vector_implementation, but the code that uses std::vector doesn't need to be recompiled because that structure doesn't need any changes.

pimpl doesn't really apply to template and code provided in header.

@Jarod42, what's pimpl?

@heretoinfinity: pointer to implementation, see pimpl
